# Haskell do clause with multiple monad types

Tags: haskell, monads, threepenny-gui

I'm using a graphic library in Haskell called [Threepenny-GUI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui). In this library the main function returns a [`UI`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.3/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#t:UI) monad object. This causes me much headache as when I attempt to unpack `IO` values into local variables I receive errors complaining of different monad types.

Here's an example of my problem. This is a slightly modified version of the standard main function, as given by Threepenny-GUI's code example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup w = do

labelsAndValues <- shuffle [1..10]

shuffle :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
shuffle [] = return []
shuffle xs = do randomPosition <- getStdRandom (randomR (0, length xs - 1))
                let (left, (a:right)) = splitAt randomPosition xs
                fmap (a:) (shuffle (left ++ right))
```

Please notice the fifth line:

```
labelsAndValues <- shuffle [1..10]
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘UI’
Expected type: UI [Int]
  Actual type: IO [Int]
In a stmt of a 'do' block: labelsAndValues <- shuffle [1 .. 10]
```

As to my question, how do I unpack the `IO` function using the standard arrow notation (`<-`), and keep on having these variables as `IO ()` rather than `UI ()`, so I can easily pass them on to other functions.

Currently, the only solution I found was to use [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO), but this causes conversion to the `UI` monad type, while I actually want to keep on using the `IO` type.

Comment: You can't change monad half way through a do block

Comment: What do you mean that you want to keep on using the IO type? Would `liftIO $ do ... a block of IO code ...` be what you're looking for?

Comment: Following the conclusions from this thread, I've opened a new question of how to integrate print. any help would be greatly appreciated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988595/haskell-ui-do-clause-how-to-print

Comment: @vondip would you able to say how you used liftIO to convert to UI monad? I have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906879/monad-and-monadio-for-custom-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `do` block is for a specific type of monad, you can't just change the type in the middle.

You can either transform the action or you can nest it inside the `do`. Most times transformations will be ready for you. You can, for instance have a nested `do` that works with `io` and then convert it only at the point of interaction.

In your case, a `liftIOLater` function is offered to handle this for you by the ThreePennyUI package.

> `liftIOLater :: IO () -> UI ()`
>
> Schedule an IO action to be run later.

In order to perform the converse conversion, you can use `runUI`:

> `runUI :: Window -> UI a -> IO a`
>
> Execute an UI action in a particular browser window. Also runs all scheduled IO action.

Comment: In my case I'm trying to use some random int list and then display it to screen, it's not clear how to separate the io action to be executed at a later stage then

Comment: `UI`is an instance of `MonadIO`, so `liftIO` is enough to to handle the OP's issue (cf. [the answer to the follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988739/2751851)). `liftIOLater` is only meant to be used in a handful of trickier cases (e.g. actions that should be ran during GUI initialisation only after the rest of the GUI has been set up).

Answer (score 5):

This is more an extended comment - it doesn't address the main question, but your implementation of `shufffle`. There are 2 issues with it:

1. Your implementation is inefficient - *O(n^2)*.
2. `IO` isn't the right type for it - shuffle has no general side effects, it just needs a source of randomness.

For (1) there are several solutions: One is to use `Seq` and its [`index`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:index), which is *O(log n)*, which would make `shuffle` *O(n log n)*. Or you could use [`ST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) [arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html) and one of the [standard algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to get *O(n)*.

For (2), all you need is threading a random generator, not full power of `IO`. There is already nice library [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.5/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) that defines a monad (and a type-class) for randomized computations. And another package already provides the [`shuffle` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-extras-0.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Extras.html#v:shuffle). Since `IO` is an instance of `MonadRandom`, you can just use `shuffle` directly as a replacement for your function.

Answer (score 2):

Under the cover, do is simply syntactic sugar for >>= (bind) and let:

```
do { x<-e; es } =   e >>= \x -> do { es }
do { e; es }    =   e >> do { es }
do { e }        =   e
do {let ds; es} =   let ds in do {es}
```

And the type of bind:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So yeah it only "supports" one Monad