# Haskell UI do clause, how to print?

Tags: haskell, monads, threepenny-gui

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981044/haskell-do-clause-with-multiple-monad-types/30987004#30987004). I'm using a graphic library in Haskell called [Threepenny-GUI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui). In this library the main function returns a [`UI`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#t:UI) monad object. I'm trying to execute a simple print command with no success. What is a right work around to enable printing for debugging purposes.

Code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = startGUI defaultConfig setup

setup :: Window -> UI ()
setup w = do

print "debug message 1 "
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘UI’
Expected type: UI ()
  Actual type: IO ()
In a stmt of a 'do' block: print "labels and values "
```

Comment: Your `do` block must contain only one monad (ie either `UI` or `IO` but not both). If you want to debug in Haskell, a debugger might be useful.

Comment: How do I support print then?

Comment: You should try to preserve the formatting of your Haskell code in your code blocks. The code in your question has a parse error because there are no spaces before `print`. One thing that helps is StackOverflow shortcut Ctrl-k. If you highlight a block of text in a question or answer and hit Ctrl-k, it will indent each line by 4 spaces. As far as I know, this shortcut isn't officially documented anywhere but it's handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the types, this is a good application of [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO). `liftIO` has a type `MonadIO m => IO a -> m a` so it can be used like this:

```
liftIO (print "debug message 1")
```

The type of that expression can be `UI ()` since `UI` is an instance of `MonadIO` and `print "debug message 1"` has the type `IO ()`.

Comment: The only reason to apply liftio then is to wrap the unused result of print so it won't shout at me?

Comment: @vondip No. The unused output is `()`. The type of the IO action is `IO ()`. In Haskell, IO actions are first-class values, so the value `print "debug message 1"` is the IO action that prints that message, not `()`.

Comment: To give another example, if you want to read in a `String` from `stdin` inside of `UI`, you could write: `do ... ; someInput <- liftIO
 getLine ; ...`(note that the type of `getLine` is `IO String`). `liftIO` lifts IO actions.

Comment: By the way: if you wanted to print to the console in response to a button click or some other UI event, rather than during the GUI initialisation, you would use either [`onEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.2/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:onEvent) or [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.2/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:on). In that case, the `liftIO` would appear in the `(a -> UI void)` callback passed to `onEvent`/`on`.