# Monad and MonadIO for custom type

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, io-monad

I have a Logger type of kind `* -> *` which can take any type and log the value in a file. I am trying to implement this in a monadic way so that I log and keep working the same. My code looks like

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

instance Functor Logger where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Logger where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

newtype Logger a = Logger a deriving (Show)

instance Monad (Logger) where
  return  = Logger
  Logger logStr >>= f = f logStr

instance MonadIO (Logger) where
  liftIO a = do
    b <- liftIO a
    return b


logContent :: (Show a) => a -> Logger a
logContent a = do
  b  <- liftIO $ logContent2 a
  return b


logContent2 :: (Show a) => a -> IO a
logContent2 a = do
    fHandle <- openFile "test.log" AppendMode
    hPrint fHandle a
    hClose fHandle
    return (a)
```

The liftIO function goes on endless loop as it calls itself. I am not able to do b <- a either. Can someone help on getting MonadIO implementation right ?

Comment: `liftIO a = do { b <- liftIO a; ...` <- here you call `liftIO` recursively for argument itself. Hence the infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think `MonadIO` works like you think it works. Look at [all defined instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO) of `MonadIO`. See the pattern? All the instances apart from `IO` itself are transformers, and in order to be a `MonadIO` they need to transform a `MonadIO`. IOW if you want your monad to be a `MonadIO`, it needs to contain an actual `IO a` value somewhere inside, directly or indirectly. Otherwise you cannot lift from `IO a` to `Logger a`, because you can never escape the `IO`.

Comment: But what if I want to convert from one monad type to another ? This will help me in chaining from one monad to another to create a flow ?

Comment: Your `Logger` monad is identical to the [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity) monad. Since `Identity` doesn't have a `MonadIO` instance, neither can your `Logger`. However, there is a `MonadIO` instance for [`IdentityT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html#t:IdentityT).

Comment: You need to start by deciding what Logger is going to do that IO doesn't already do. For instance, should it carry a file handle for the log file? Once you know that the design will start to become clearer.

Comment: With liftIO :: IO a -> m a, I should be able to pass any IO monad and convert to another monad type 'm' right ?

Comment: No, not in general.  The signature is actually `liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a`, and the `MonadIO m` bit isn't just a trivial constraint.  If a monad `m` has a `liftIO` instance, that's an indication that it **already has IO functionality**, either because it **is** the IO monad or because it's part of a monad stack with `IO` at its base.  Your `Logger` monad can't have a `liftIO` instance (except one that's either unsafe or doesn't terminate) because your `Logger` monad has no existing IO functionality.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, I think you've misunderstood what `MonadIO` and `liftIO` do.

These typeclasses and functions come from `mtl` library.  Rather unfortunately, `mtl` stands for "monad transformer library", but [mtl is not a monad transformer library](https://blog.jle.im/entry/mtl-is-not-a-monad-transformer-library.html).  Rather, `mtl` is a set of typeclasses that allow you to take a monad that --- and this is important --- **already has a particular type of functionality** and provide that monad with a consistent interface around that functionality.  This ends up being really useful for working with actual monad transformers.  That's because `mtl` allows you to use `tell` and `ask` and `put` to access the `Writer`, `Reader`, and `State` functionality of your monad transformer stack in a consistent way.

Separately from this transformer business, if you already have a custom monad, say that supports arbitrary IO and has `State` functionality, then you can define a `MonadState` instance to make the standard state operations (`state`, `get`, `gets`, `put`, `modify`) available for your custom monad, and you can define a `MonadIO` instance to allow an arbitrary IO action to be executed in your custom monad using `liftIO`.  However, none of these typeclasses are capable of adding functionality to a monad that it doesn't already have.  In particular, you can't transform an arbitrary monadic action `m a` into an `IO a` using a `MonadIO` instance.

Note that the `transformers` package contains types that **are** capable of adding functionality to a monad that it doesn't already have (e.g., adding reader or writer functionality), but there is no transformer to add `IO` to an arbitrary monad.  Such a transformer would be impossible (without unsafe or nonterminating operations).

Also note that the signature for `liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a` puts a `MonadIO` constraint on `m`, and this isn't just a trivial constraint.  It actually indicates that `liftIO` only works for monads `m` that **already have IO functionality**, so either `m` *is* the IO monad, or it's a monad stack with `IO` at its base.  Your `Logger` example doesn't have IO functionality and so can't have a (sensible) `MonadIO` instance.

Getting back to your specific problem, it's actually a little bit hard to steer you right here without knowing exactly what you're trying to do.  If you just want to add file-based logging to an existing IO computation, then defining a new transformer stack will probably do the trick:

```
type LogIO = ReaderT Handle IO

logger :: (Show a) => a -> LogIO ()
logger a = do
  h <- ask
  liftIO $ hPrint h a

runLogIO :: LogIO a -> FilePath -> IO a
runLogIO act fp = withFile fp AppendMode $ \h -> runReaderT act h
```

and you can write things like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runLogIO start "test.log"

start :: LogIO ()
start = do
  logger "Starting program"
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Please enter your name:"
  n <- liftIO $ getLine
  logger n
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ n
  logger "Ending program"
```

The need to add `liftIO` calls when using IO actions within the `LogIO` monad is ugly but largely unavoidable.

This solution would also work for adding file-based logging to pure computations, with the understanding that you have to convert them to IO computations anyway if you want to safely log to a file.

The more general solution is to define your own monad *transformer* (not merely your own monad), like `LoggerT m`, together with an associated `MonadLogger` type class that will add file-based logging to to any IO-capable monad stack.  The idea would be that you could then create arbitrary custom monad stacks:

```
type MyMonad = StateT Int (LoggerT IO)
```

and then write code that mixes monadic computations from different layers (like mixing state computations and file-based logging):

```
newSym :: String -> MyMonad String
newSym pfx = do
  n <- get
  logger (pfx, n)
  put (n+1)
  return $ pfx ++ show n
```

Is this what you what you're trying to do?  If not, maybe you could describe, either here or in a new question, how you're trying to add logging to some example code.

Comment: Thanks @K. A. Buhr I will try out the suggestions you mentioned and update here